# React navigator not moving between screens

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

My app closes when I press the switch screen button. I don't see any error output.
I did a version check and there was no problem.

The function I wrote for the button works

**Router.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import First from "./First";
import Second from "./Second";
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const Router = () =>{
    return(
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="First">
                <Stack.Screen name="First" component={ First }/>
                <Stack.Screen name="Second" component={ Second }/>
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}

export default Router;
```

**First.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {View,Text,Button} from 'react-native';


const First = ( props ) =>{
    const gotoSecond = () => {
        console.log("First");
        props.navigation.navigate("Second");
        console.log("second")
    }
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Hello First Page!</Text>
            <Button title="Go SecondPage!" onPress={gotoSecond}/>
        </View>
    );

};

export default First;
```

**Second.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {View,Text} from 'react-native';

const Second = () =>{
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Hello Second Page!</Text>
        </View>
    );

};

export default Second;
```

**OS:Android,**
**Emulator:Genymotion.**

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm using ADV instead of Genymotion, problem solved.